# Object型の変数をString型に直したい

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-spreadsheet

ライブラリにPerserを追加して、以下のコードでスクレイピングを行ったところ、取得した情報がObject型になっていて、getvalue();や.toStringを用いてString型に変換しようとしても変換できませんでした。

よって正規表現による文字列の抽出や変換ができないのですが、どなたかString型に変換する方法に心当たりはありませんか？

これら郵便番号やホームページの順番がバラバラなので、文字列型にしたうえで、正規表現による検索を行いたいと考えています。
Splitメソッドを使用したのは、このように、配列にしたうえで、電話番号、住所など判断して、一つずつ貼り付けることができないか期待していました。

```
function Scrapcontact() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetURL  = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付け'), true);
  var sheetWork  = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ペースト&作業用シート'), true);
  
for(i=2; i<=11; i++){
  var r   =  i   -    1;
  let URL = sheetURL.getRange('B'  +   i).getValue();
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  let content = response.getContentText("utf-8");
  var contact= Parser.data(content).from('<td class="sameSize" id="accessInfoListDescText110">').to('</td>').iterate();
  sheetWork.getRange('E'  +   r).setValue(contact);
  var Contact2 = sheetWork.getRange('E'  +   r).getValue();



  var strContact = Contact2.split('<br/>',8);
  
  console.log(strContact);
   console.log(typeof(strContact));
}
}
```

これによって生成される情報は以下のようになります
例

```
13:41:21    情報  [ '〒111-0000 東京都十鬼田区王魔市111　王魔ビル',
  '【採用チーム】山下一夫（やましたかずお）',
  'お問い合わせ電話番号　000-0000-0000',
 '',
  '※採用に関するお問い合わせはメールにてお願いいたします。',
  '【MAIL】kennganntougishamotomu@antamoyarukai.jp' 
 '【ホームページ】http://antamooretoyarukai',]
13:41:21    情報  object
13:41:22    情報  [ '東京都真柏連合ビル77 真柏連合',
  'お問い合わせ電話番号　000-0000-0000',
 '〒111-1111 ',
  '※採用に関するお問い合わせはメールにてお願いいたします。',
  '【MAIL】shinpakurenngo_shinainalsoutosama@hometataeyo.uyamae.soshitegebokutonarunoda' 
 '【ホームページ】http://antamooretoyarukai',
 '【採用チーム】白濱健一　白濱未海',]
13:41:21    情報  object
```

このようにコードを追記しましたが、やはりString型として認識されていないためか、execメソッドもmatchメソッドも機能しませんでした。
そのままセルに貼り付けることはできても、特定の一文のみを正規表現で抽出してセルに貼り付けることができない状態です

```
  var Postcode = Contact2.exec( /\d/);

  console.log(Contact2);
  console.log(Postcode);
```

---

[image: 期待していた動作]

Comment: Object型（この場合、細かく分類すると配列です）を文字列にしたいならば、`toString` メソッドでよいはずです。
ただ、それは質問者さんがやりたい事では無いのでしょう。
`console.log` で出力する前に `split` メソッドを使用したのはどのような動作を期待したものですか？

Comment: これら住所や電話番号等を、分割して一つずつのセルに貼り付けることができないか？
という動作を期待してSplitメソッドを使用して、<br/>を消そうとしました。

住所も電話番号も順番がバラバラなので、正規表現で郵便番号なのか電話番号なのか、それらを判断してからでないと一つずつのセルへの貼り付けができません。

Comment: 「Splitメソッドを使用したのは、このように、配列にしたうえで、」とのことですので、意図どおりできているように思います。
文字列に戻す必要はなさそうですがいかがでしょうか。
（配列の各要素は文字列です。念のため）

Comment: 文字列なら、正規表現で郵便番号か、電話番号かなど、順番がバラバラなため判断してからセルに貼り付けたいのですが、String型になっていないためかexecメソッドやmatchメソッドが機能しないのです

Comment: 配列にした後の各要素をそれぞれ正規表現で処理したいということでしょうか。
その場合は、`for` ループなどで各要素を一つずつ扱えばよいです。
そうではなく、全体に対して正規表現を使用したいのならば、配列にする前（`Contact2`）の文字列をそのまま使えばよいです。

Comment: 配列に直す前に行えば、execメソッドやmatchメソッドで正規表現を使用できるのですね
ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strContact`は文字列の配列なので、`for` などでその配列要素を処理するのが良いでしょう。

```js
for (let str of strContact) {
  if (str.match(/\d{3}-\d{4}/)) {
    ...
}
```

---

型を調べるときは、`typeof(strContact)` よりは `strContact.constructor.name` の方がわかりやすい結果になります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
この場合、If文で処理した文字列は、どうやったらログに出力できますか？

for (let str of strContact) {
  if (str.match(/\d{3}-\d{4}/)) {
  let Postcode  = str.match(/\d{3}-\d{4}/);
  
  console.log(Postcode);

このような書き方で、一応は出力されました。

Comment: それで期待通りの結果なら間違いではないでしょう。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございました