# 従業員数を数値型変換したい

Tags: 正規表現, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

以下のコードで取得した従業員数を、正社員、名などの文字を省いて数値型に置換したいです。
恐らく配列になっているためか、Machメソッドなどの文字列操作用メソッドで操作できず、Valueメソッドで数字のみ取得することもできません。

Perserは外部ライブラリで、スクレイピングを行うため使用していますが、どのようなライブラリを使っても同じ問題に突き当たると考えたため、説明を省きます。

```
function employee() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetURL  = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付け'), true);
  var sheetWork  = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ペースト&作業用シート'), true);
  
for(i=2; i<=11; i++){
  var v   =  i   +   10;
  let URL = sheetURL.getRange('A'  +   i).getValue();
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  let content = response.getContentText("utf-8");
  var employee= Parser.data(content).from('<td class="sameSize" id="corpDescDtoListDescText270">').to('</td>').iterate();


  console.log(employee);
  console.log(typeof(employee));
}
}
```

このコードで出てくる情報は以下のようになります。

```
10:47:35    情報  [ '605名（2022年10月現在）' ]
10:47:35    情報  object
10:47:35    情報  [ '580名(2022年4月1日現在）' ]
10:47:35    情報  object
10:47:36    情報  [ '578名（正社員、契約社員、パート等含む）※2023年3月時点<br/>' ]
10:47:36    情報  object
10:47:36    情報  [ '550名（2023年4月現在）' ]
10:47:36    情報  object
10:47:37    情報  [ '850名<br/>' ]
10:47:37    情報  object
10:47:37    情報  [ '775名（2023年4月1日現在）' ]
10:47:37    情報  object
10:47:38    情報  [ '561名（2022年2月末時点）' ]
10:47:38    情報  object
10:47:38    情報  [ '正社員：782名<br/>※2022年2月末時点' ]
10:47:38    情報  object
10:47:39    情報  [ '517名（2022年12月末現在）<br/>※派遣社員含む' ]
10:47:39    情報  object
10:47:39    情報  [ '900名（グループ全体 2,100名）' ]
```

以下のような形に直したいです。

```
10:47:35    情報  [ '580' ]

10:47:36    情報  [ '578' ]

10:47:36    情報  [ '550' ]

10:47:37    情報  [ '850' ]

10:47:37    情報  [ '775' ]

10:47:38    情報  [ '561' ]

10:47:38    情報  [ '782' ]

10:47:39    情報    [ '517' ]

10:47:40　  情報    [ '900' ]
```

Comment: [以前の質問への回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/95720/3054)で配列の要素に対して `for` で処理を行なう方法が説明されています。今回も同じでよいはずです。 （要素が1つと決まっているならば、`employee[0]` とするだけでもよいでしょう。）

Comment: ありがとうございます、確かに同様の手段で切り出せば解決しそうです

考えすぎていました。